# MSMQ service is not available in failover cluster

Tags: msmq, failovercluster

I want to cluster my service and since my service uses the msmq service I have to also cluster the msmq service. I successfully created the cluster and added both my service and msmq service as resource of the cluster, and they are both brought online. Then the problem comes, my service said the msmq service is not available.

There are some tips for clustering msmq service, like my service should check the option "User Network Name for computer name", the msmq service on local machine should run as the local system account and so on. I followed all those tips, but the msmq service is still not available to my service.

Anyone has experience for this stuff? I'd appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you what worked for us (after a lot of trying).
We set (in the code) the

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_,"ClusterName");
```

ClusterName -> is the msmq cluster service name.
in the queue path you should set the machine name to the msmq cluster name.
`{MsmqClusterName}/Private/QueueName`  try it